# I want to send two different emails to two different addresses usign php in same function

Tags: php

So I would love my code to update merchants that register on my site when a product is ordered from them and at the same time send the same email to our company email address.
While the code is being sent to our company email address, the mail to the merchant is not sending.
Could you please show me where I could be wrong? Thank you.

PLEASE NOTE THAT the email variable belongs to the merchant and is mostly a gmail account. Could this be a restriction from gmail or what?

```
function mail_merchants_and_shoply($cart_code){
        $conn = $this -> connection;
        $merchant_sent = false;
        $shoply_sent = false;
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM business_account ORDER BY business_id DESC")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $id = $row['business_id'];
            $stat = "NEW";
            $email = $row['email_add'];
            $name = $row['business_name'];
            $c_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cart_db WHERE business_id = '$id' AND cart_code = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $cart_code)."'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            $merchant_mail_body = "<h2>NEW ORDER</h2><ul>";
            while($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($c_query)){
                $p_id = $arr['product_id'];
                $p_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$p_id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                $p_arr = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query);
                $image = $p_arr['product_image1_url'];
                $price = $p_arr['product_price'];
                $name = $p_arr['product_name'];

                $image = "<img src = 'https://www.shoply.ng/backend/$image' style = 'max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px'/>";

                $merchant_mail_body.="<li>$name</li> <li>$image</li> <li> $price</li>";
            }
            $merchant_mail_body .="</ul>";

            $mail_subject = "NEW SHOPLY ORDER";
            // $mailHead = implode("\r\n", ["MIME-Version:1.0","Content-type:text/html; charset =utf-8"]);

            $mailHead = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $mailHead .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            
            // Additional headers
            $mailHead .= 'From: Shoply<orders@shoply.ng>' . "\r\n";
            if(mail($email, $mail_subject, $merchant_mail_body, $mailHead)){
                $merchant_sent = true;
            }

            $s_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cart_db WHERE cart_code = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $cart_code)."'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            $o_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_code = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $cart_code)."'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            $o_arr = mysqli_fetch_array($o_query);
            $location = $o_arr['delivery_location'];
            $phone = $o_arr['delivery_phone'];
            $user_fname = $_SESSION['user_fname'];
            $shoply_mail_body = "<h2>NEW ORDER</h2> FROM: $user_fname <ul>
            <li><b>Address:</b> $location</li>
            <li><b>Phone Number: </b>$phone</li>";
            // $f_arr = mysqli_fetch_array($s_query);
            // $customer_id = $f_arr['customer_id'];
            // $c_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_id= '$customer_id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            // $c_arr[]
            

            
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($s_query)){
                $p_id = $row['product_id'];
                $p_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$p_id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                $p_arr = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query);
                $image = $p_arr['product_image1_url'];
                $price = $p_arr['product_price'];
                $name = $p_arr['product_name'];
                $image = "<img src = 'https://www.shoply.ng/backend/$image' style = 'max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px'/>";

                $shoply_mail_body.="<li>$name</li> <li>$image</li> <li> $price</li>";
            }  
            $shoply_mail_body .="</ul>";
            $email = "sales@shoply.ng";
            $mail_subject = "NEW SHOPLY ORDER";
            // $mail_head = implode("\r\n", ["MIME-Version:1.0","Content-type:text/html; charset =utf-8"]);

            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            
            // Additional headers
            $headers .= 'From: Shoply<orders@shoply.ng>' . "\r\n";


            if(mail($email, $mail_subject, $shoply_mail_body, $headers)){
                $shoply_sent = true;
            }

            if($merchant_sent && $shoply_sent){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using php mailter instead of the built in mail function.

PHP's mail() function uses the server's basic mail server and on shared hosts these generally have a terrible email reputation and as such are blockedby many recipient servers. PHP Mailer allows you to communicate directly with any external web server, even via Gmail if you wish to send emails.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer